# Gropby multiple columns and multiple aggregations

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Current DF

| Product Nr | Product Name | Sales Rev | Sales Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | ProductX | 11,1 |  |
| Product2 | ProductY | 22,2 |  |
| Product1 | ProductX |  | 1 |
| Product2 | ProductY |  | 2 |
| Product3 | ProductZ | 33,3 |  |
| Product3 | ProductZ |  | 3 |

Attempting to group by columns Product Nr and Product Name, and get sum of Sales Rev and Sales Qty. Expected result:

| Product Nr | Product Name | Sales Rev | Sales Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | ProductX | 11,1 | 1 |
| Product2 | ProductY | 22,2 | 2 |
| Product3 | ProductZ | 33,3 | 3 |

Attempted code:

```
df.groupby(['Product Nr', 'Product Name']).agg({'Sales Rev': 'sum', 'Sales Qty':'sum' })
```

This returns only aggregated columns, without variable columns. Any suggestions?

Suggested by Quinten, returns stacked df, but it lacks records. Updated current df and expected output.

```
df.groupby('Product Nr', as_index=False).first()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
df.groupby('Product Nr', as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
  Product Nr Product Name Sales Rev  Sales Qty
0   Product1     ProductX      11,1        1.0
1   Product2     ProductY      22,2        2.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Something is not quite right though, output df doesnt contain all records. Please see updated current df and expected output.